# traffic shaping using ifb redirect

Tags: traffic-shaping, tc, traffic-filtering

I would like to use ifb to perform some shaping for multiple virtual interfaces. However, I am not sure how to tell the ifb interface to egress to a dedicated egress interface

Right now vnet0 -> mirrer action mirror -> ifb0

I would like to to establish the following

vnet0 -> mirrer action mirror to ifb0 -> filter match to eth4

I notice by default, all packets are dropped on ifb0 interface. I tried an ingress mirred action from ifb0 to eth4 but no packets are being forwarded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected behavior for ifb